# Access violation reading c++

Tags: c++, access-violation

/*Unhandled exception at 0x00AB6591 in Building.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*/

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996) 

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cassert>
using namespace std;

class Building
{
private:
    int height;
    int area;
    char*address;
public:
    Building();
    Building(int, int, char*);
    ~Building();
    Building(const Building &);
    Building & operator=(const Building&);

    int getHeight()const;
    int getArea()const;
    char* getAddress()const;
    void print()const;


    void setHeight(int);
    void setArea(int);
    void setAddress(char*);
};


Building::Building()
{
    height = 0;
    area = 0;
    address = new char[1];
    address = NULL;
}


Building::Building(int h, int ar, char* a)
{
    height = h;
    area = ar;

    address = new char[strlen(a)+1];
    assert(address != NULL);
    address = NULL;
}


Building::~Building()
{
    delete[]address;
}



Building::Building(const Building & b)
{
    height = b.height;

    area = b.area;

    address = new char[strlen(b.address) + 1];
    assert(address != NULL);
    strcpy(address,b.address);
}


Building & Building::operator=(const Building& b)
{
    if (this != &b)
    {
        delete[]address;
        height = b.height;

        area = b.area;

        address = new char[strlen(b.address) + 1];
        assert(address != NULL);
        strcpy(address, b.address);
    }
    return *this;
}

int Building::getHeight()const
{
    return height;
}


int Building::getArea()const
{
    return area;
}


char* Building::getAddress()const
{
    return address;
}


void Building::print()const
{
    cout << "Height = " << getHeight() << endl << "Area = " << getArea() << endl << "Address = " << getAddress() << endl;
}


void Building::setHeight(int h)
{
    height = h;
}


void Building::setArea(int ar)
{
    area = ar;
}


void Building::setAddress(char* adr)
{
    strcpy(address, adr);
}
//==========================================================================================================
class House :public Building
{
private:
    int floors;
    char*name;
public:
    House();
    House(int,int,char*,int=0, char* =" ");
    ~House();
    House(const House&);
    House& operator=(const House&);

    int getFloors()const;
    char* getName()const;


    void setFloors(int);
    void setName(char*);


    void print()const;
};

House::House()
{
    floors = 0;
    name = new char[1];
    assert(name != NULL);
    name = NULL;
}
House::House(int h, int ar, char* adr, int f, char* n) :Building(h, ar, adr)
{
    floors = f;

    name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    assert(name != NULL);
    strcpy(name, n);
}


House::~House()
{
    delete[]name;
}


House::House(const House& h) :Building(h)
{
    floors = h.floors;

    name = new char[strlen(h.name) + 1];
    assert(name != NULL);
    strcpy(name, h.name);
}

House& House::operator=(const House&h)
{
    if (this != NULL)
    {
        Building::operator=(h);
        delete[]name;
        floors = h.floors;

        name = new char[strlen(h.name) + 1];
        assert(name != NULL);
        strcpy(name, h.name);
    }
    return*this;
}

int House::getFloors()const
{
    return floors;
}

char* House::getName()const
{
    return name;
}


void House::setFloors(int f)
{
    floors = f;
}


void House::setName(char* na)
{
    strcpy(name, na);
}


void House::print()const
{
    Building::print();
    cout << "Floors: " << getFloors() << endl << "Name: " << getName() << endl;
}
//=============================================================================================================

House getBigger(House m[], int size)// a house with bigger avarage height of a floor
{
    House temp;
    int max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int avH = (m[i].getHeight() / m[i].getFloors());
        if (avH >= max)
        {
            max = avH;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return m[index];
}
//=============================================================================================================
int main()
{
    House h1(16,400,"Bla street",4,"Marion");
    h1.print();

    House h2;
    h2.setHouse();
    h2.print();


    House h3;
    h3.setHouse();
    h3.print();

    House arr[] = { h1, h2, h3 };

    House h4;
    h4=getBigger(arr, 3);
    h4.print();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have problem with my program for building and a house. It is simple maybe but I don't know why throws exception. I think that my try for user input is wrong anywhere.

Comment: Is the error the only output you get?  Are you giving it any input before it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Building constructors both set address to null.  If you are trying to print the address anywhere, your code will give you that error.

Comment: Thanks.Fix it! :)))))